# How to count outputs in Catch command by using Mathematica

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

I am using the below command in Mathematica (an example):

```
Catch[Do[i; If[EulerPhi[i] > EulerPhi[i + 1], Print[i]], {i, 1, 100}]]
```

Of course, I would like to do this for other functions (maybe) and for 100 replaced for much bigger numbers.

How to count the number of outputs (printed solutions) for this? Since they appear in a column, I cannot use count commands for table. At least, they are not working for me.

Comment: Use `Table` instead of `Do` and use `Nothing` as the 3rd arg to `If`.  And just use `i`, not `Print` in the 2nd arg.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I dind't understand. In fact, I think it didn't work. Could you please write it up here?

Comment: @Jean, I guess, that Michael E2 means something like this `Length@Table[If[EulerPhi[i] > EulerPhi[i + 1], i, Nothing], {i, 1, 100}]`. The output of Table can be counted very easy..

Comment: Sorry I am busy. @Rom38 is right. Tho if counting is all that is needed you cold use cnt=0; Do[If[..., ++cnt], { I, 100}]; cnt

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Sow` and `Reap` instad of `Catch`.

```
Do[ If[EulerPhi[i] > EulerPhi[i + 1], Print@Sow@i]
    , {i, 1, 100}] // 
Reap // Last // Last // Length
```

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CollectingExpressionsDuringEvaluation.html

Answer (score 2):

Alternative ways to use `Reap/Sow`

1. with `Scan`:

```
Reap[Scan[Sow[#, EulerPhi[#] > EulerPhi[# + 1]]&, Range@100], True, Length@#2&][[2, 1]]
```

> 47

2. with `Do`:

```
Reap[Do[Sow[i, EulerPhi[i] > EulerPhi[i + 1]], {i, 100}], True, Length@#2&][[2, 1]]
```

> 47